# SSRS Rendering format PPT / PPTX

Tags: reporting-services, rendering, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2012

On reporting services is the ability to view reports on multiple rendering format except for PPT / PPTX.

Looking at the net there Aspose.Slides the tool does good apparently, but that is not free. So I saw that there was the possibility of developing its own rendering extension
Microsoft explains here but it is not complete and accurate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms154018%28v=sql.120%29.aspx
So I would have the top hand if anybody know how.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint export has been requested a long time ago ([Add Rendering of Powerpoint to Reporting Services export format](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/310639/add-rendering-of-powerpoint-to-reporting-services-export-format)).
It has not been included in Reporting Services at this time, so I'm afraid you listed most of the options:

- Buy an external library like Aspose.Slides.
- Create a PowerView report and [export it as PowerPoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh759323.aspx), as specified [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/a53c1c30-9c59-4e51-9579-e225e54a5d4a/ssrs-report-export-to-power-point), but only in this specific configuration:

  > If you can use SSRS 2012 SharePoint Integrated Mode, we can create a
  >   Powerview report, and export this report to PowerPoint.
- Believe me, you don't want to create your own rendering extension from scratch to export to PowerPoint, go to the next bullet point.
- If you know a tool that can convert one of the already available export formats in SSRS to PowerPoint, you could try to follow this tutorial ([Zip Rendering Extension for SQL Server Reporting Services 2005/2008/2012](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488883/Zip-Rendering-Extension-for-SQL-Server-Reporting-S)), and create an additional rendering extension that takes the output of another extension and converts it.

Do not forget that you can also vote on the [above connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/310639/add-rendering-of-powerpoint-to-reporting-services-export-format) to have it out-of-the-box in a future release.